# How do I make python use this random generated color?

Tags: python, random, generator, turtle-graphics

So as of now, I have this code;

```
import turtle
import random

def getColor():
    selection = random.randint(1,3)
    if selection == 1:
        return "green"
    elif selection == 2:
        return "red"
    else:
        return "blue"

def drawPerson(my_turtle, x, y):
    my_turtle.penup()
    my_turtle.goto(x,y)
    my_turtle.pendown()
    my_turtle.pensize(3)

    xul.color = getColor()
    print(xul.color)
        if xul.color == "green":
            xul.color("green")
        elif xul.color == "red":
            xul.color("red")
        else:
            xul.color("blue")

    xul.forward(90)
    xul.left(90)
    xul.forward(90)
    xul.left(90)
    xul.forward(90)
    xul.left(90)
    xul.forward(90)
    xul.left(90)


xul = turtle.Turtle()
drawPerson(xul,150,150)
drawPerson(xul,-150,150)
drawPerson(xul,-150,-150)
drawPerson(xul,150,-150)
drawPerson(xul,0,0)
```

The problem is.. I can generate the color, it prints the color it draws all the shapes, but I cannot figure out how to make the color actually get applied to the turtle before it draws. I have tried things like;

```
xul.color("getColor")
```

and numerous other things, but I cannot seem to figure it out.. If someone could just give me the line of code that I am missing I'd greatly GREATLY appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, can delete 
        `if xul.color == "green":
            xul.color("green")
        elif xul.color == "red":
            xul.color("red")
        else:
            xul.color("blue")`

this whole set of string didn't do anything and returned an error was just something I was testing out

Comment: you have to call the function, not the function name. ie `xul.color(getColor())`

Comment: So i took out `xul.color = getColor()` added in instead `xul.color(getColor())` instead, now it shows the drawPersons with their colors(thanks) but now it doesnt print the color that it is using it instead says <bound method Turtle.color of <turtle.Turtle object at 0x0000000003617400>>
it runs the code, just when it prints the xul.color it doesnt say red, green, or blue

Comment: `xul.color` is a function, if you want it to return the color, add braces `xul.color()` and dont pass a parameter.

Comment: Alright thanks a bunch so far, so i added in print(xul.color()) and it prints the color now in the box when it is drawing the squares, however now it is showing the color 2 times as coordinates shows it like ('red', 'red') if you know what i mean

Comment: you should really read up on the [turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.color). considering that I have no experience in turtle yet am able to answer these questions means you could probably fix these problems yourself :) (btw its returning two colors because there is pen color and fill color, you should probably explicitly set each one separately)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your second function like so:

```
def drawPerson(xul, x, y):
    xul.penup()
    xul.goto(x,y)
    xul.pendown()
    xul.pensize(3)

    xul.color(getColor())

    xul.forward(90)
    xul.left(90)
```

etc. — assuming you want the drawing steps inside the function and that wasn't just an indentation mistake.

Your first function is fine, but there's an easier way:

```
def getColor():
    return random.choice(['red', 'green', 'blue'])
```

Comment: Oh I see, that way looks much cleaner, thanks makes it easier for future :D but for this assignment I am working on we needed to use the longer way :). Yeah I figured out it has to be `xul.pencolor(getColor())` followed by `print(xul.pencolor())`